# filtering only excel files in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on excel sheets in C# and i am struck to select only excel sheets.
I tried the following code

```
OpenFileDialog browseFile = new OpenFileDialog();
browseFile.DereferenceLinks = true;
browseFile.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|Excel 2010|*.xlsx";
// browseFile.Filter = "Link Files (*.lnk)|*.lnk";

browseFile.Title = "Browse Excel file";
if (browseFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
```

Using this code am not only getting excel sheets but also ended up getting the shortcut files.
Can anyone suggest how can i restrict the shortcut files too.

Comment: Counter example from SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350802/can-the-net-openfiledialog-be-setup-to-allow-the-user-to-select-a-lnk-file

Comment: You might also try combining the filter:  `Excel Files|*.xls,*.xlsx`

Comment: @BlackMaggie I want the link files to be restricted. not to allow them.

Comment: @G_S: try setting `DereferenceLinks=false;` - I think this is your problem.

Comment: @code4life I tried setting it to false .Even that didnt help.

Comment: `OpenFileDialog.DereferenceLinks`

if set to true will return the path of the file the shortcut link points to.
it is also set to `true` by default.
Let me try if there is a way to remove the lnk files altogether.

Comment: Yes even i will try out again for a way to remove the lnk files during filtering.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please see if you are ok with the below approach. 
In the meantime let me try if something is possible using reflections.

```
    OpenFileDialog openKeywordsFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openKeywordsFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    openKeywordsFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
    openKeywordsFileDialog.ValidateNames = true;
    openKeywordsFileDialog.DereferenceLinks = false; // Will return .lnk in shortcuts.
    openKeywordsFileDialog.Filter = "Excel |*.xlsx";
    openKeywordsFileDialog.FileOk += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(OpenKeywordsFileDialog_FileOk);
    var dialogResult =  openKeywordsFileDialog.ShowDialog();


void OpenKeywordsFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
         OpenFileDialog fileDialog = sender as OpenFileDialog;
         string selectedFile = fileDialog.FileName;
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedFile) || selectedFile.Contains(".lnk"))
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid Excel File");
             e.Cancel = true;
         }
         return;
}
```

Comment: You can also consider calling the Win32 API directly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How to use this OpenKeywordsFileDialog_FileOk() ? Is it a method or a system generated event.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add handler for the `FileOk` event.
Have edited the answer now.

Comment: Yes this worked.But is there any way not to show the .lnk files instead of showing them and restrict them after clicking?

Answer (score 10):

Try to use this. Hope this help! Cheers! :D

browseFile.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";

Comment: Even this is not working.This ends up showing only shortcuts.I want only excel without shorcuts.

Comment: Thanks - I needed to know to use the semicolon for separating the extensions (i.e. .xls from .xlsx).