# Wpf file browser dialog select shortcut file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using on WPF Win32 file browser dialog to select a file in the filesystem. Now my problem is, when I select an shortcut file ending with .ink,  it shows the application path not the shortcut(.ink) path.

For example I want to select snoop shortcut

[image: Shortcut]

as filepath, I've got.

[image: Filepath]

How can I get the path from shortcut not from application?

**Update**
I am trying restrict with

```
 Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Win32.OpenFileDialog();
 ofd.Filter = "Link (*.lnk)|*.lnk";
```

but only .lnk it is possible to select. It should be possible to select other files too, not only .lnk file.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758941/how-to-get-the-current-directory-path-of-applications-shortcut and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414152/get-target-of-shortcut-folder

Comment: this is usually how shortcut works, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350802/can-the-net-openfiledialog-be-setup-to-allow-the-user-to-select-a-lnk-file to get the lnk file itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `OpenFileDialog.DereferenceLinks` property.

> > Gets or sets a value indicating whether a file dialog returns either the location of the file referenced by a shortcut or the location of the shortcut file (.lnk).

```
odf.DereferenceLinks = false;
```

For the update question, just add `All Files|*.*|` :

```
ofd.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Link (*.lnk)|*.lnk";
```